# not able to access the video's duration, when the "apiready" event is called.

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

i am using the following to access the video duration.

```
   var player = DM.player(document.getElementById("DMplayer"), {
        video: url,
        width: '100%',
        params: {
            autoplay: false,
            mute: true,
            controls: false
        }
    });
```

and to access the duration data

```
    player.addEventListener('apiready', function(event) {

        console.log(player.duration)

    });
```

I am getting the values as NaN.

Is there any other event, where i can get the duration info ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from your question whether this is a Vimeo video though it is tagged that way. Therefore I will answer with that assumption which may be incorrect.

The Vimeo player.js repo has every event and their associated data well documented here: https://github.com/vimeo/player.js#events. I believe this will greatly help you.

To answer your question more specifically- if you are asking about the total duration of a video that information is attached to many events: `play`, `pause`, `ended`, `timeupdate`, `progress` and `seeked`. In addition to the duration information you may also get the `percent` of the video which implies the percent progress and the `seconds` which gives the current time in seconds watched of the video. Below is the relevant code in action:

```
player.on('play', function(data) {
        console.log("video duration:", data.duration); 
        });
```

You can see the full example here: https://jsfiddle.net/rebeccas/07td7uL4/64/